# Add Row dynamically with SelectPicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-select

Morning,

I have a table with selectpicker in first column.
and i would like to add dynamically rows.
Actually after adding row first column it's ok but i can't select for second column.
Thks for your help.

My table :

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <Select class="selectpicker" name="item_desc[]" id="item_desc" type="integer" onchange="select_fields(this)">
                <option> </option>
                @foreach ($articles as $article)
                    <option>{{$article->id}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </Select>
        </td>
        <td class="writefields" name="item_fields[]"></td>
        <td><i class="btn far fa-trash-alt" onclick="remove_row(this)"></i></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

`

My function to add row :

```
function add_row(){
     var root = document.getElementById('add_table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
     var rows = root.getElementsByTagName('tr');
     var clone = cloneEl(rows[rows.length -1]);
     cleanUpInputs(clone);
     root.appendChild(clone);
 }

 function cloneEl(el){
     var clo = el.cloneNode(true);
     return clo;
 }

 function cleanUpInputs(obj){
     for (var i = 0; n = obj.childNodes[i]; ++i){
         if(n.childNodes && n.tagName != 'INPUT'){
             cleanUpInputs(n);
         }else if (n.tagName == 'INPUT' && n.type == 'text') {
             n.value = '';
         }
     }
 }
```

My select_fields function:

```
function select_familyfields(e)
{
    ...
    var selectionfamille = e.value;

  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/achats/selection",
            data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, code_item : selection },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {       $(e).parents('tr').find('.item_fields[]').text(data.natureachat.LibNatureAchat); 
          ...
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you please be more specific? Is the select menu on the newly created row not firing the onchange event? And where is the select_fields() function?

Comment: Thks for your feedback. See below my select_fields() function.

Comment: I Think my problemn is to remove bootstrap-select after adding new row by clone into add row function. I can select with success into first row. But i'cant make a new select after adding new row. my new clone ligne have still first row item selected.

Comment: Did you resolve this ?

Comment: not yet... looking for solution !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using selectpicker in your code so this plugin creates its own dynamic htmls and assign `ids ,data-attribute` to them so when you *clone* your tr they are copy as well that's why you don't see option inside newly added dropdown nor they are able to selected.

Instead , one way to make this work is to store *cloned* tr in some variable where *selectpicker* is not yet initialize . Then , whenever `add_row()` function is call simply use that cloned tr to append inside your `tbody` and then intialize your selectpicker using `$("#add_table tbody tr:last select").selectpicker()` .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var cloned = $("#add_table tbody tr:first").clone() //keep clone for later use..
$("select[name*=item_desc]").selectpicker() //intialize your slectpicker
function add_row() {
  $(cloned).find("input").val("") //empty any input..
  $(cloned).find(".writefields").text("") //clear td 
  $("<tr>" + $(cloned).html() + "</tr>").appendTo($("#add_table tbody")) //append to your tbody..
  $("#add_table tbody tr:last select").selectpicker() //intialize newly added selct...
}

function select_fields(e) {
  var selectionfamille = e.value;
  console.log(selectionfamille)

  /* $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/achats/selection",
     data: {
       _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
       code_item: selection
     },
     dataType: "JSON",
     success: function(data) {*/
  //just for demo...
  $(e).parents('tr').find('[name="item_fields[]"]').text("abcxyz") //data.natureachat.LibNatureAchat;

  /*}
  });*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<table id="add_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <!--remove selectpicker class and id..-->
        <select name="item_desc[]" onchange="select_fields(this)">
          <option> </option>

          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="writefields" name="item_fields[]">Smethings...</td>
      <td><i class="btn far fa-trash-alt" onclick="remove_row(this)">Delete</i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="add_row()">Add</button>
```

Comment: Thks Swati for your help. it's successful !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because your `<Select` element has an ID and you need to make that unique? Try this addition to your `cleanUpInputs` function

```
function cleanUpInputs(obj){
     let cloneCounter = document.getElementById('add_table').getElementsByTagName('tbody').length + 1
     obj.getElementsByClassName('.selectpicker')[0].id = "item_desc" + cloneCounter;
     for (var i = 0; n = obj.childNodes[i]; ++i){
```

Comment: After tests i have this error :"obj.querySelector is not a function"

Comment: I updated my answer, can you try that? Thanks

Comment: Error after test : "obj.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined"